# React Native Password TextInput throws warnings

Tags: react-native

I have a TextInput field that I want to use for password as such

```
<TextInput secureTextEntry="true"></TextInput>
```

but I keep getting this warning in the iOS emulator and also in the chrome debug tools

```
Failed propType: Invalid prop `secureTextEntry` of type `string` supplied to `TextInput`, expected `boolean`.
```

I am on "react-native": "^0.16.0"

Comment: I should add that the functionality works but I get a warning.

Comment: Possibly try secureTextEntry={true}  ? Idk, just a thought though.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Please add that as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextInput secureTextEntry={ true }></TextInput>
```